# Fill container with minimum number of children

Tags: jquery, magento, append

Wanting to populate a container with a minimum number of children, I'm wondering what the best way of doing this is. For now I got the following, but it's very bloated... The idea is to have a container that gets populated dynamically. I want the container to always be filled with a minimum of 4 child elements.

```
for(var k=0; k<parent.length; k++) {
    var section = parent[k],
        article = parent[k].querySelectorAll('.child');

    console.log(article);

    if(article.length === 1) {
        $('.parent').append('<li class="empty-child"></li><li class="empty-child"></li><li class="empty-child"></li>');
    } else if(article.length === 2) {
        $('.parent').append('<li class="empty-child"></li><li class="empty-child"></li>');
    } else if(article.length < 4) {
        $('.parent').append('<li class="empty-child"></li>');
    }
}
```

It just doesn't feel right to me. I do know I could use .append(new Array..., maybe that's the way to go?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a `for` loop that starts at article length. If the length is already 4 or more it won't do anything

```
var $parent =  $('.parent')
for(var j = article.length; j< 4; j++){
    $parent.append('<li class="empty-child"></li>');
}
```

Comment: Hmz, I think I'm missing something basic here. If I implement it as follows, I get extra unwanted '.empty' divs.

`var $parent = $('.parent');
 for(var l=0; l<$parent.length; l++) {
  var section = $parent[l];
   article = $parent[l].querySelectorAll('.child');
   
  for(var m=article.length; m<4; m++) {
   $parent.append('<div class="empty"></div>');
  }
 }`

The outcome of this is

`
.parent
.child
.child
.child
.empty
.empty
.empty
.empty
.empty
.empty
.empty
.empty
.empty
`

Comment: Why did you start at zero? That's not what I proposed

Comment: Woops, mea culpa.. I'll implement it like you initially suggested and will come back to you.

Comment: Hmz, I've made a pen for this to test, but still seem to be overlooking something :| 
https://codepen.io/jeffklunder/pen/rrwxMp?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

I got around to test your code the way you intended and I'm happy to say it works like a charm! For those of you out there searching for a similar answer, here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.section').each(function() {
    var child = $(this).find('li');

    for(var i=child.length; i<4; i++) {
        $(this).append('<li>empty</li>');
    }
});
```

});